# how to dynamically generate model names in a service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lodash, linq.js

I have a service that i am using to apply a unique number to a model name. the result i am getting is this

```
 "sectionInputs": [
  {
    "model": "price_min1"
  },
  {
    "model": "price_max2"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_occ3"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_mod4"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fin5"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_vdl6"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_uc7"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fut8"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_con9"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_total10"
  }
]
```

i need this to each have '1'. and then in the next object array i need them to have '2', etc...  as of now every object array looks like this. i have a plunker with everything setup. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zTCUcRQ70rnnUCnvytX?p=preview)

```
function sectionInputSvc(sectionInputs) {

var vm = this;

vm.sectionInputsArry = sectionInputs;

vm.sectionInputs = function () {
    var arry = [];
    var counter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.sectionInputsArry.length; i++) {
        counter++
        var obj = {
            model: vm.sectionInputsArry[i].model + counter
        };
        arry.push(obj);
    };

    return arry;

};
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT 2]**

in app.js...

```
sections[i].sectionInputs = sectionInputSvc.sectionInputs(sections[i],i);
```

and in section.service.js...

```
    function sectionInputSvc(sectionInputs) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.sectionInputsArry = sectionInputs;
    var obj2={};

    vm.sectionInputs = function (obj2,num) {
        var arry = [];
        var counter = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < vm.sectionInputsArry.length; i++) {
            counter++
            var obj = {
            model: vm.sectionInputsArry[i].model + num
        };
            arry.push(obj);
        };

        return arry;

    };
};
```

Comment: almost. the objects in the array now have the same number attached to them. problem is every object in the array has the same number '1'. need to increment by 1

Comment: really? I thought I'd got it wrong but in the opposite direction to the one you're describing. See my revised answer for how I understand it should be...

Comment: ok, it works. but i explained my self wrong. i the the value to change. right now you made it so the key changes. model needs to stay the same.

Comment: Model needs to stay the same? I don't understand. Can you give us an example of how you would like the `"sectionInputs"` array to end up looking?

Comment: the plunker json has a array with 3 objects. each object has a nested array 'sectionInputs'. the first sectionInput array needs to have '1' added to the end of the property value, 'price_min1', price_max1, etc....   then in the next sectionInput array needs to have '2' added to the end of each property value. price_min2,price_max2, etc...

Comment: got it. see my revised revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using linq.js, and assuming the suffixes do not already exist on the names:

```
vm.sectionInputs = function () {
    return Enumerable.From(vm.sectionInputsArry).Zip(Enumerable.ToInfinity(1),
        "{ model: $.model+$$ }"
    ).ToArray();
};
```